# c++ static string object crashes in release mode

Tags: c++, static, stdstring

I am attaching the minimal code below. The problem is with static string object that is leaking memory. I think the problem is with the string object not being initialized properly. The program runs fine in Debug mode but crashes in the Release mode.

I am using Windows 7 : 64bit - MS Visual Studio 2012

I have tried initializing the object with empty string but it did not solve the problem as suggested here 
[what to do if debug runs fine, but release crashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4012498/what-to-do-if-debug-runs-fine-but-release-crashes)

I enabled "Treating warnings as Errors" also did not help as there are no warning as suggested by the following post
[what to do if debug runs fine, but release crashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4012498/what-to-do-if-debug-runs-fine-but-release-crashes)

There were some other suggestions too like "static initialization order fiasco" but I do not think its related to my issue.

Any help is appreciated

> main.cpp

```
//main.cpp
#include "MyParameters.h"

using namespace std ;

int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
  try
  { 
        cout << "MyParameters::m_outputDir: " << MyParameters::m_outputDir << endl ;

        bool initialized = MyParameters::initialize( "myimo.xml" ) ;                

        cout << "MyParameters::m_outputDir: " << MyParameters::m_outputDir << endl ;
        cout << "Terminating the application..." << endl ;

  }
  catch ( std::exception &e )
  {
    cout << e.what() << std::endl;
  }
}
```

> MyParameters.h

```
//MyParameters.h
#ifndef __MY_PARAMETERS_H
#define __MY_PARAMETERS_H

#include <string>
#include <iostream>

 #include <QString>

class MyParameters 
{

public:

  static std::string m_outputDir; ///< output directory

  static bool initialize( const QString &xmlFile  );

private:

  MyParameters();
};

#endif /* __MY_PARAMETERS_H */
```

> MyParameters.cpp

```
//MyParameters.cpp
#include "MyParameters.h"
#include <QDir>

std::string MyParameters::m_outputDir ;    

using namespace std ;

MyParameters::MyParameters()
{

}

bool MyParameters::initialize( const QString &xmlFile )
{
  m_outputDir = QDir::current().absoluteFilePath( xmlFile ).toStdString(); // --> this crashes 
    //m_outputDir = "C:\\Dev\\" ; // --> works fine
    cout << "m_outputDir: " << m_outputDir << endl ;

    cout << "myparameters.xml file reading is complete" << endl ;
  return true;
}
```

Comment: [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) please.

Comment: What is the output of your program, before it crashs...?

Comment: @jpo38: It prints on console **"Terminating the application..."** the last line of the main and then crashes.

Comment: Same if you add return 0 at the end of your main function? Was Qt compiled correctly? Try a simple Qt program only creating a static std::string.

Comment: There's a lot you could and should trim to narrow down the problem.  For example, what if you alter `ParameterFileParser::checkDirectory` so that it just returns a copy of the input string?  What if `setDirectory` just sets the `value` to a fixed string and returns `true`?  Take @Borgleader's advice and create an MVCE.  You may solve your own problem on the way.

Comment: TMTR but you're probably up against the [static initialization order fiasco](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/static-init-order.html). It's nearly always a good idea to consult the FAQ before asking.

Comment: thanks guys for the suggestions. I ll try them now.

Comment: i have reduced the example to minimal. The program crashes at `QDir::current().absoluteFilePath( xmlFile ).toStdString();` but if i use a fixed string then it works fine. The crash occurs only in the release mode, debug mode runs fine.

Comment: Nice and now split that line up into 3 different lines and see which fails.

Comment: I have broken it down to 3 separate lines but the program crashes when the main exits. It does not crash at `QDir::current().absoluteFilePath( xmlFile ).toStdString();`. When I am using a fixed string instead of `QString.toStdString()` then the program runs fine in release mode. Also it runs fine in the Debug mode but crashes only in the release mode. I can not figure out why it is crashing when main exits. Thanks a lot for all the suggestions from you guys.

Comment: ok, i think i have found the problem. The program was not crashing in the ReleaseWithDebugInfo. But I tried again in ReleaseWithDebugInfo, compiled the program and enabled the flag Properties->Linker->Debugging->Generate Debug Info (Yes /DEBUG). Then when I executed the program it crashed and I clicked the DEBUG button. the CallStack showed me **dynamic atexit destructor for `MyParameters::m_outputDir`**. Now how to solve this issue is another question which I will try to figure out but I have no idea what **dynamic atexit** is. Thanks a lot for the help.