# Performance bottleneck at _L_unlock_16

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads, gperftools

I am trying to use google perf tools CPU profiler for debugging performance issues on a multi-threaded program. With single thread it take 250 ms while 4 threads take around 900ms.

My program has a mmap'ed file which is shared across threads and all operations are read only. Also my program creates large number of objects which are not shared across threads. (Specifically my program uses CRF++ library to do some querying). I am trying to figure out how to make my program perform better with multi threads. Call graph produced by CPU profiler of gperf tools shows that my program spends a lot of time (around 50%) of time in **_L_unlock_16**.

Searching web for _L_unlock_16 pointed to some bug reports with canonical suggesting that its associated with libpthread. But other than that I was not able to find any useful information for debugging.

A brief description of what my program does. I have few words in a file (4). In my program I have a processWord() which processes a single word using CRF++. This processWord() is what each thread executes. My main() reads words from the file and each threads runs processWord() in parallel. If I process a single word(hence only 1 thread) it takes 250ms and so if I process all 4 words(and hence 4 threads) I expected it to finish by same time 250 ms, however as I mentioned above it's taking around 900ms. 
This is the callgraph of the execution - https://www.dropbox.com/s/o1mkh477i7e9s4m/cgout_n2.png

I want to understand why my program is spending lot of time at _L_unlock_16 and what I can do to mitigate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yet again the **_L_unlock_16** is not a function of your code. Have you looked at the stracktraces **above** that function? What are the callers of it when the program waits? You've said that the program wastes 50% waiting inside. But, which part of the program ordered that operation? Is it again from memory alloc/dealloc ops?

The function seems to come from libpthread. Does CRF+ handle threads/libpthread in any way? If yes, then maybe the library is illconfigured? Or maybe it implements some 'basic threadsafety' by adding locks everywhere and simply is not built well for multithreading? What does the docs say about that?

Personally, I'd guess that it ignores threads and that you have added all the threading. I may be wrong, but if that's true, then the CRF++ probably will not call that 'unlock' function at all, and the 'unlock' is somwhow called from your code that orchestrates the threads/locks/queues/messages etc? Halt the program a few times and look at who called the unlock. If it really spends 50% sitting in the unlock, you will very quickly know who causes the lock to be used and you will be able to either eliminate it or at least perform a more refined research..

EDIT #1:

Eh.. when I said "stacktrace" I meant stacktrace, not callgraph. Callgraph may look nice in trivial cases, but in more complex ones, it will be mangled and unreadable and will hide the precious details into "compacted" form.. But, fortunatelly, here the case looks simple enough.

Please observe the beginning: "Process word, 99x". I assume that the "99x" is the call count. Then, look at "tagger-parse": 97x. From that:

- 61x into rebuildFeatures from which 41x goes right into unlock and 20(13) indirectly into it
- 23x goes to buildLattice fro which 21x goes into unlock

I'd **guess** that it was the CRF++ uses locking quite heavily. For me, it seems that you simply observe the effects of CRF's internal locking. It certainly is not lockless internally.

It seems to lock at least once per "processWord". It's hard to say without looking at code (is it opensource? I've not checked..), from stacktraces it would be more obvious, but IF it really locks once per "processWord" that it could even be a sort of a "global lock" that protects "everything" from "all threads" and causes all jobs to serialize. Whatever. Anyways, clearly, it's the CRF++'s internals that lock and wait.

If your CRF objects are really (**really**) not shared across threads, then remove threading configuration flags from CRF, pray that they were sane enough to not use any static variables nor global objects, add some own locking (if needed) at the topmost job/result level and retry. You should have it now much faster.

If the CRF objects are shared, unshare them and see above.

But, if they are shared behind the scenes, then there's little doable. Change your library to a one that has a better threading support, OR fix the library, OR ignore and use it with current performance.

The last advice may sound strange (it works slowly, right? so why to ignore it?), but in fact is the most important one, and you should try it first. If the parallel tasks have similar "data profile", then there is very probable that they will try to hit the same locks in the same approximate moment of time. Imagine a medium-sized cache that holds words sorted by its first letter. At the toplevel there's array of, say, 26 entries. Each entry has a lock and a list of words inside. If you run 100 threads that will each first check "mom" then "dad" then "son" - then all of that 100 threads will first hit and wait for each other at "M", then at "D" then at "S". Well, approximately/probably of course. But you get the idea. If the data profile were more random then they'd block each other far less. Mind that processing ONE word is a .. small task and that you try to process the same word(s). Even if the internal CRF's locking is smart, it is just bound to hit the same areas. Try again with a more dispersed data.

Add to that the fact that **threading costs**. If something was guarded against races with use of locks, then every lock/unlock costs because at least they have to "halt and check if the lock is open" (sorry very imprecise wording). If the data-to-process is small in relation to the-amount-of-lockchecks, then adding more threads will not help and will just waste the time. For checking one word, it may even happen that the sole handling of a single lock takes longer than processing the word! But, if the amount of data to be processed were larger, then the cost of flipping a lock compared to processing the data might start being neglible.

Prepare a set of 100 or more words. Run and measure it on one thread. Then partition the words at random and run it on 2 and 4 threads. And measure. If not better, try at 1000 and 10000 words. The more the better, of course, keeping in mind that the test should not last till your next birthday ;)

If you notice that 10k words split over 4 threads (2500w per th) works about 40%-30%-or even 25% faster than on one thread - here you go! You simply gave it a too small job. It was tailored and optimized for bigger ones!

But, on the other hand, it may happen that 10k words split over 4 threads does not work faster, or worse, works slower - then it might indicate that the library handles multithreading very wrong. Now try the other things like stripping threading from it or repairing it.

Comment: I have modified original description with more details on my program and a call graph. Also I don't have any specific locks in my program not even on CRF++ and I am using a modified version of CRF++ which is thread safe and re-entrant without use of any locks.

Comment: See my edit. Without looking at the exact code both yours and CRF's, there's hard to say anything more. I'll not have time to dig into it further, sorry. If above hints won't be enough, maybe someone else will show up who knows the precise problem and solution for this library.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. But I haven't been able to solve this yet. On checking strace -c it shows that futex system call takes 90% of user CPU time. Also cachegrind shows lots of data cache misses. I am debugging in that direction now.

Comment: I've just noticed you've marked the answer. Have you found the cause of the problem? What was that?

Comment: It was a dump thing I did. My profiling methodology was wrong. I was using C++ clock() api. Running it with linux time showed the real time.